# Directory of the "open files dialog" in Kicad

Tags: pwd, file-opening, wxwidgets

I need to make an application (Kicad, in this context) launch its "Open File" dialog in current working directory (where I launched Kicad).

Is there any standard environment variable for this purpose?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by “control the open file dialogs”? What kind of control are you talking about? Visual theme? Window position and size? File filters? I can't think of an environment variable that would do any of these things anyway. Whatever it is, it would be specific to a GUI framework or to an application.

Comment: @Gilles I updated the question.

Comment: Ah, ok. That's what the current directory is for. Unfortunately some applications are very badly designed and don't observe the current directory. I've never seen one that used an environment variable instead: if the developers were thinking about what they were doing, they'd use the standard method.

Comment: Ok, so I accept this behaviour as another "design decision(!)" of Kicad... Thank you.